# Issue to import libraries/moduls for a ROS2 python subscriber

Tags: ros2, python, ros-humble, msg-subscriber

I am new to use ROS in my project. I have installed ROS2 humble on Ubuntu 22.04. I need to import different python codes/functions as modules to a ROS2 subscriber (python code).

They are:

```
1) `common_utils.py` in `utils` folder
2) `build_network` which is a function in `pointpillar.py`
```

Both python codes are located in another folder which is not a ROS2 package (`home/user/Machine_Learning`) and its directory is different from subscriber directory (`home/user/DL_ws/src/object_detection/object_detection/pc_subscriber.py`).

In my subscriber code, I changed the directory to `Machine_Learning` folder, then I used `from utils import common_utils` and `from pointpillar import build_network`. With/without updating `package.xml` (adding `utils` and `pointpillar` for `</exec_depend>`), then `colcon build`, when I use `ros2 run object_detection listener`, I get this error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'` or `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pointpillar'`.

How can I solve this issue?

I appreciate any help in advance.

Thanks,

Abbas

Answer (score 1):

You can't add miscellaneous directories of python code to your ros project using `package.xml`. In the short term, you can manually add the full directory path to the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable (this is a native python feature, not a ros feature.)

However, creating this type of dependency is fragile and not a good idea if you expect to ever share this code with anyone else. It would be better to create an actual ros package so you can document the dependency in the object_detection `package.xml`.